c# method in Startup.cs using Hangfire is not working as expected
I have the following Hangfire reference in my Startup.cs file:
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Prod_SendUserEmails", () => SendEmailNotices(), Cron.Daily);

SendEmailNotices() is just a method that loops through users like this:
        public async Task SendEmailNotices()
        {

            var users= _context.UserGroup.AsEnumerable();

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                 SendAlertEmail(user.Id);
            }
        }

So it runs everyday, but each user is getting multiple copies of the same email alert.
The SendAlertEmail() method is just a simple function that connects to an SMTP server and sends email...there is no loop or anything that would account for multiple emails being sent.
I also contactd the systems admin who maintains the SMTP server, and there is nothing that would cause it to send out multiple emails.
So could it be Hangfire?
Thanks!

Have you checked the hangfire dashboard to see if it is executing multiple times?

@Jawad I did check...I don't see anything there that would indicate that it's executing multiple times...just once everyday... thanks!

Are you sure the every user gets the multiple emails ? Cuz this smells to me like an hangfire default retry mechanism. If one of the emails fails to be sent hangfire restarts the job if exception is not handled. So it would start all over and send emails again until it finishes the job completely. I would add [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)] on the SendEmailNotices to see if it fails on first try.
